# When does $A \cap C \subseteq B \cap D \Longrightarrow A \subseteq B$ and $C \subseteq D$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Basically, we know that $A\subseteq B$ and $C\subseteq D$ implies that 
$A \cap C \subseteq B \cap D$. I was wondering under which (additional) conditions (such as convexity, nonemptyness or being on a specific class of sets) can we establish the converse. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Since $B\cap D=D\cap B$ you'd be able to conclude that $A\subseteq B$ and $A\subseteq D.$

Comment: But basically, there are too many cases where $A\not\subseteq B$ to exclude. As long as every $a\in A\setminus B$ is not in $C,$ you have $A\cap C\subseteq B.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an element is either in a set or not, with $4$ sets, there are $2^4$ cases,

There are $4$ of them will not hold:
\begin{align}
&S_1\subseteq\color{red}{A\cap B^c\cap C^c\cap D}\tag{1}\\
&S_2\subseteq\color{\orange}{A\cap B^c\cap C^c\cap D^c}\tag{2}\\
&S_3\subseteq\color{blue}{A^c\cap B\cap C\cap D^c}\tag{3}\\
&S_4\subseteq\color{pink}{A^c\cap B^c\cap C\cap D^c}\tag{4}\\
\end{align}
Counter examples can be construct as following: ($S_i\neq\varnothing$ where $i\in[1,4]$)
$$\color{\lightblue}{S_i\cap }A \cap \color{\lightblue}{S_i\cap }C \subseteq \color{\lightblue}{S_i\cap }B \cap \color{\lightblue}{S_i\cap }D \not\Rightarrow \color{\lightblue}{S_i\cap }A \subseteq \color{\lightblue}{S_i\cap }B\land \color{\lightblue}{S_i\cap }C \subseteq \color{\lightblue}{S_i\cap }D\tag{$*$}$$

Here is how do we find a counter example with $S_1$:
\begin{align}
\text{Take Universe, }&U=\{t_1,t_2,t_3\}\\
&\color{red}A=\{t_1,t_2\}&A^c=\{t_3\}\\
&B=\{t_3\}&\color{red}{B^c}=\{t_1,t_2\}\\
&C=\{t_3\}&\color{red}{C^c}=\{t_1,t_2\}\\
&\color{red}D=\{t_1,t_2\}&D^c=\{t_3\}\\
&S_1=\color{red}{A\cap B^c\cap C^c\cap D}=\{t_1,t_2\}\neq\varnothing\\
\text{The expression become: }&\underset{A_1=\{t_1,t_2\}}{\underline{S_1\cap A}} \cap \underset{C_1=\varnothing}{\underline{S_1\cap C}} \subseteq \underset{B_1=\varnothing}{\underline{S_1\cap B}} \cap \underset{D_1=\{t_1,t_2\}}{\underline{S_1\cap D}}\\\Rightarrow &S_1\cap A \subseteq S_1\cap B\land S_1\cap C \subseteq S_1\cap D\\
\equiv&~\varnothing\subseteq\varnothing\Rightarrow\{t_1,t_2\}\subseteq\varnothing\land\varnothing\subseteq\{t_1,t_2\}\\
\equiv&~\top\Rightarrow\bot\land\top\\
\equiv&~\bot
\end{align}

Hence $A_1,B_1,C_1,D_1$ is a counter example, and we have $12$ other cases that the expression will hold.

---

Update:
(Like @Eleonore Saint James said, you can use a [Truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to see why this is the only $4$ cases.)
\begin{array}{cccc|c@{}c@{}c@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}c@{}ccc@{}c@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}c@{}c@{}c}
A&B&C&D&(&(&(&A&\cap&C&)&\subseteq&(&B&\cap&D&)&)&\Rightarrow&(&(&A&\subseteq&B&)&\land&(&C&\subseteq&D&)&)&)\\\hline
1&1&1&1&&&&1&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&&1&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&&&\\
1&1&1&0&&&&1&1&1&&0&&1&0&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&&1&1&1&&0&&1&0&0&&&\\
1&1&0&1&&&&1&0&0&&1&&1&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&&1&1&1&&1&&0&1&1&&&\\
1&1&0&0&&&&1&0&0&&1&&1&0&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&&1&1&1&&1&&0&1&0&&&\\
1&0&1&1&&&&1&1&1&&0&&0&0&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&&1&0&0&&0&&1&1&1&&&\\
1&0&1&0&&&&1&1&1&&0&&0&0&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&&1&0&0&&0&&1&0&0&&&\\
\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}1&&&&1&0&0&&1&&0&0&1&&&\mathbf{\color{red}0}&&&1&0&0&&0&&0&1&1&&&\\
\color{\orange}1&\color{\orange}0&\color{\orange}0&\color{\orange}0&&&&1&0&0&&1&&0&0&0&&&\mathbf{\color{\orange}0}&&&1&0&0&&0&&0&1&0&&&\\
0&1&1&1&&&&0&0&1&&1&&1&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&&0&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&&&\\
\color{blue}0&\color{blue}1&\color{blue}1&\color{blue}0&&&&0&0&1&&1&&1&0&0&&&\mathbf{\color{blue}0}&&&0&1&1&&0&&1&0&0&&&\\
0&1&0&1&&&&0&0&0&&1&&1&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&&0&1&1&&1&&0&1&1&&&\\
0&1&0&0&&&&0&0&0&&1&&1&0&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&&0&1&1&&1&&0&1&0&&&\\
0&0&1&1&&&&0&0&1&&1&&0&0&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&&0&1&0&&1&&1&1&1&&&\\
\color{pink}0&\color{pink}0&\color{pink}1&\color{pink}0&&&&0&0&1&&1&&0&0&0&&&\mathbf{\color{pink}0}&&&0&1&0&&0&&1&0&0&&&\\
0&0&0&1&&&&0&0&0&&1&&0&0&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&&0&1&0&&1&&0&1&1&&&\\
0&0&0&0&&&&0&0&0&&1&&0&0&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&&0&1&0&&1&&0&1&0&&&
\end{array}

Denote $x\in S$ as $S(x)$ we know that:

$A\cap C\subseteq B\cap D\Rightarrow A\subseteq B\land C\subseteq D$ if and only if:

$$\forall_x((A(x)\land C(x))\to (B(x)\land D(x))\Rightarrow (A(x)\to B(x))\land (C(x)\to D(x)))$$
This is why the table works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am trying to wrap my head around why those are the only cases for which my statement wont hold. Let me just clarify something: This step is part of a more involved proof. I have managed to show that 
$A \cap C \subseteq  B \cap D$ and I also know that all these sets are nonempty. As I have excluded all the four cases (since $A.B,C$ and $D$ are nonempty) Can I conclude that $A\subseteq B$ and $C \subseteq D$?

Comment: @NoobNoob With only $A,B,C,D\neq \varnothing$, the statement might be False, for a counter example we can take: $$A=\{t_1\},B=\{t_1\},C=\{t_1,t_2\},D=\{t_1\}$$

Comment: And yes, if it's not in one of the four cases, the statement is True, be more specific what this saying is instead to say $A,B,C,D\neq \varnothing$, what we have is when $S_i=A\cap B\cap C\cap D\neq\varnothing$, then statement $(*)$ must be True, that $A_i=S_i\cap A,B_i=S_i\cap B~$etc.  are valid choices of sets.

Comment: Thanks for the super complete answer!

Answer (score 1):

The sentence expressed in set theoretic language should be true in exactly the same cases as its translation in the language of propositional logic.

[image]